# scroll top navigation bar similiar to flipkart app ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uinavigationbar

I have a logo on a navigation bar. Beneath it, I have a searchbar with three bar buttons on its both sides.
 The searchbar and bar buttons are put in a UIView which is beneath the navigationbar.
 I want to implement a functionality where with a very small pinch of scroll on the tableview by user, the navigationbar should move above with animation with scroll up and should come down with animation for scroll down.
 Along with this, the searchbar should occupy the position of the logo while scrolling up and should come at its original position when scrolling down.

This is the same functionality implemented in Flipkart app on the Home page.
I tried using SQTShyNavigationBar by Cocoa Controls
https://github.com/cbpowell/SQTShyNavigationBar, but that does not adjust the position of my search View.
Please help me with this.